# Echo random string within value element

Tags: php

I have an input element ( search box ) and in the value element I am trying to echo a random string.

So example: I have

```
<input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" id="search" value="<?php echo($num);?>" />
```

For the random string i am using this crude code

```
<?php
 $num = Rand (1,3); 
  switch ($num)
  {
  case 1:
  echo "eg. Sydney, NSW";
  break;
  case 2:
  echo "eg. Manly, NSW";
  break;
  case 3:
 echo "eg. Jimboomba, QLD";
 }
?>
```

For some reason, I just get the value echoed as the php code.

Any ideas, I have pulled most of my hair out

Comment: Just wondering if i should use include_once in value element and point to the php rand file...but that didnt work either

Comment: Is your page executed by PHP interpreter? This might be a reason for displaying your PHP code.

Comment: I am not sure what that means, but it is a php page, and the content block is pure html

Comment: Here's a test on Codepad: http://codepad.org/RVP8c18p And it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @jared, but that echoes numeric value in value element, I just want to echo random string from the list into the value element ( perhaps my code is crap )

Comment: Well, you have the `$num` in there... What else is supposed to happen? That `echo`, you're just going right by it; it's not in `$num`, but it's probably somewhere else in your site's page source. Made a variable, and instead of an `echo` in the `switch`, do `$rantext = "...";` and then later `value="<?php echo $rantext;?>"`.

Comment: I would probably do something like this (if I understand you correctly): http://codepad.org/rHB97K21 The list is in an `array`, and with that I can generate a (not very) "random number" and use that to access that text in the array. Keep in mind there's only three entries, too. not very random.

Comment: Cheers @JaredFarrish thats sweet now :)